# Convert each page of a multi-paged pdf into separate png files in R

Tags: r, pdf, imagemagick

I have seen a [few questions asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617270/convert-pdf-to-png-in-r) involving trying to convert a pdf into a png but none of the answers show how to save each page of a multi-paged pdf as a different png file.

Starting out with an example 13-page pdf:

```
# exmaple pdf 
example_pdf <- "https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1312/1312.2789.pdf"
```

**How can I save each page of the pdf as a different png file?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can create a png of each page using the `image_read_pdf` function from the `magick package`:

```
#install magick package
install.packages("magick")
library("magick")

# creating magick-image class with a png for each page of the pdf
pages <- magick::image_read_pdf(example_pdf)
pages


# saving each page of the pdf as a png
j <- 1:13
for (i in j){
pages[i] %>% image_write(., path = paste0("image",i,".png"), format = "png")

}
```

This would save each page as "image(page number).png" in your main directory file.