# Read text from PDF

Tags: r

I am using pdftools in R to get text from pdf, but I am having several problems geting the information.

With this pdf for [example](http://www.mediafire.com/file/f1ecy19mpdm88cy/Factura.pdf/file) when I try to get the text:

```
library(pdftools)
pdf_text(paste(ruta, "Factura.pdf"))
```

(Ruta is where you put the pdf).
With this file I don´t get anything. This step works with pdf which are perfect (like [this](http://jornadasciberseguridad.riasc.unileon.es/archivos/ejemplo_esp.pdf)), but when the pdf has scanned information lost accurancy.

Is there any other way to get text from a pdf with R which solve this type of problem?

Thanks

Comment: You don't get anything because there is no text in this PDF, only an image. You need OCR if you want to get text from an image.

Comment: Have a look at the `tesseract` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, [your example](http://www.mediafire.com/file/f1ecy19mpdm88cy/Factura.pdf/file) is an image PDF, which is an image just store as PDF.

If you want to extract text from the image PDF. you can use [Tesseract](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tesseract/vignettes/intro.html)

```
library(tesseract)
eng <- tesseract("eng")
text <- tesseract::ocr("http://jeroen.github.io/images/testocr.png", engine = eng)
cat(text)
```

Also, you need to convert pdf to img first. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617270/convert-pdf-to-png-in-r)

> `im.convert("bm.pdf", output = "bm.png")`